# Passing pointer to pointer to float from Java through JNA to a C dynamic library

Tags: java, c, jna, catboost

Catboost offers a [dynamic C library](https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/c-plus-plus-api_dynamic-c-pluplus-wrapper-docpage/), which theoretically can be used from any programming language.

I'm trying to call it through Java using JNA.

I'm having a problem with the `CalcModelPrediction` function, defined in the [header file](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/master/catboost/libs/model_interface/model_calcer_wrapper.h) as follows:

```
EXPORT bool CalcModelPrediction(
    ModelCalcerHandle* calcer,
    size_t docCount,
    const float** floatFeatures, size_t floatFeaturesSize,
    const char*** catFeatures, size_t catFeaturesSize,
    double* result, size_t resultSize);
```

In Java, I've defined the interface function as follows:

```
public interface CatboostModel extends Library {
        public Pointer ModelCalcerCreate();
        public String GetErrorString();
        public boolean LoadFullModelFromFile(Pointer calcer, String filename);
        public boolean CalcModelPrediction(Pointer calcer, int docCount,
                PointerByReference floatFeatures, int floatFeaturesSize,
                PointerByReference catFeatures, int catFeaturesSize,
                Pointer result, int resultSize);
        public int GetFloatFeaturesCount(Pointer calcer);
        public int GetCatFeaturesCount(Pointer calcer);
    }
```

and then I'm calling it like this:

```
CatboostModel catboost;
Pointer modelHandle;

catboost = Native.loadLibrary("catboostmodel", CatboostModel.class);
            modelHandle = catboost.ModelCalcerCreate();
if (!catboost.LoadFullModelFromFile(modelHandle, "catboost_test.model"))
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot load Catboost model.");
}

final PointerByReference ppFloatFeatures = new PointerByReference();
final PointerByReference ppCatFeatures = new PointerByReference();
final Pointer pResult = new Memory(Native.getNativeSize(Double.TYPE));

float[] floatFeatures = {0.5f, 0.8f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.1f, 0.5f, 0.4f, 0.8f, 0.3f, 0.3f} ;
String[] catFeatures = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
int catFeaturesLength = 0;
for (String s : catFeatures)
{
    catFeaturesLength += s.length() + 1;
}

try
{
    final Pointer pFloatFeatures = new Memory(floatFeatures.length * Native.getNativeSize(Float.TYPE));
    for (int dloop=0; dloop<floatFeatures.length; dloop++) {
        pFloatFeatures.setFloat(dloop * Native.getNativeSize(Float.TYPE), floatFeatures[dloop]);
    }
    ppFloatFeatures.setValue(pFloatFeatures);

    final Pointer pCatFeatures = new Memory(catFeaturesLength * Native.getNativeSize(Character.TYPE));
    long offset = 0;
    for (final String s : catFeatures) {
        pCatFeatures.setString(offset, s);
        pCatFeatures.setMemory(offset + s.length(), 1, (byte)(0));
        offset += s.length() + 1;
    }
    ppCatFeatures.setValue(pCatFeatures);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't initialize parameters for catboost");
}

try
{
    if (!catboost.CalcModelPrediction(
                modelHandle,
                1,
                ppFloatFeatures, 10,
                ppCatFeatures, 4,
                pResult, 1
                ))
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("No prediction made: " + catboost.GetErrorString());
    }
    else
    {
        double[] result = pResult.getDoubleArray(0, 1);
        log.info("Catboost prediction: " + String.valueOf(result[0]));
        Assert.assertFalse("ERROR: Result empty", result.length == 0);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Prediction failed: " + e);
}
```

I've tried passing `Pointer`, `PointerByReference` and `Pointer[]` to the `CalcModelPrediction` function in place of `float **floatFeatures` and `char ***catFeatures` but nothing worked. I always get a segmentation fault, presumably when the `CalcModelPrediction` function attempts to get elements of `floatFeatures` and `catFeatures` by calling `floatFeatures[0][0]` and `catFeatures[0][0]`.

So the question is, what's the right way of passing a multi-dimensional array from Java through JNA into C, where it could be treated as a pointer to a pointer to a value?

An interesting thing is that the `CalcModelPredictionFlat` function that accepts only `float **floatFeatures` and then simply calls `*floatFeatures`, works perfectly fine when passing `PointerByReference`.

**UPDATE - 5.5.2018**

**Part 1**

After trying to debug the segfault by slightly modifying the original Catboost .cpp and .h files and recompiling the libcatboost.so library, I found out that the segfault was due to me mapping `size_t` in C to `int` in Java. After fixing this, my interface function in Java looks like this:

```
public interface CatboostModel extends Library {
        public boolean LoadFullModelFromFile(Pointer calcer, String filename);
        public boolean CalcModelPrediction(Pointer calcer, size_t docCount,
                Pointer[] floatFeatures, size_t floatFeaturesSize,
                String[] catFeatures, size_t catFeaturesSize,
                Pointer result, size_t resultSize);
    }
```

Where the `size_t` Class is defined as follows:

```
public static class size_t extends IntegerType {                                           
    public size_t() { this(0); }                                                           
    public size_t(long value) { super(Native.SIZE_T_SIZE, value); }                       
}
```

**Part 2**
Looking more into the Catboost code, I've noticed that `**floatFeatures` are being accessed by rows, like `floatFeatures[i]` while `***catFeatures` are accessed by rows and columns, like `catFetures[i][catFeatureIdx]`.

After changing `floatFeatures` in Java to an array of `Pointer`, my code started to work with the model trained without categorical features, i.e. `catFeatures` length is zero.

This trick, however, didn't work with `catFeatures` that are accessed through a double subscript operator `[i][catFeatureidx]`. So for now, I modified the original Catboost code so that it would accept `char **catFeatures` - an array of strings. In Java interface function, I set `String[] catFeatures`. Now I can make predictions for one element at a time, which is not ideal.

Comment: small note -- you want to replace the `Pointer[]` with `PointerByReference`. That memory address, say `x` will be the 0th element, `x+8` will be the 1st element, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, @DebosmitRay, unfortunately, I've tried `PointerByReference` and I updated the code above to reflect that. It still throws segmentation fault. Could you please check if I'm declaring and assigning a value to `ppFloatFeatures` correctly?

Comment: What does the data actually look like behind the pointer?  `float**` might be a way to return a `float*`, or it may be an array of pointers, or even an array of float arrays.  `PointerByReference` only really covers the first case.

Comment: Can you provide a native example of the required data initialization?

Comment: @techomage I've written a C program that uses libcatboostmodel.so library. In it, everything works fine if I declare input parameters like this:
```const float floatFeatures[] = {0.4f, 0.8f, 0.3f};
float *pFloat;
float **ppFloat;
pFLoat = &FloatFeatures;
ppFloat = &pFloat;```

Then, passing `ppFloat` to `CalcModelPrediction` in place of `float **floatFeatures` works fine when the C code iterates over `floatFeatures` through double-subscript operator `[0][0]`.

Comment: @technomage I think I need to pass an array of float arrays and an array of string arrays. To be precise, the `CalcModelPrediction` function generalised `floatFeatures` and `catFeatures` to 2-D arrays of `float` values and `char*` values.

Comment: So if you're iterating over a 2d array, you can either treat it as a single dimension of size RxC and do your own indexing, or, if your rows are of unequal sizes, use an array of pointers to access the addresses of each individual row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make it all work with the original Catboost code and `libcatboost.so`.

The Java interface function is defined like this. Note that in order to emulate a 2D array (or a pointer to a pointer) of float values and strings, I'm using `Pointer[]` type.

```
public interface CatboostModel extends Library {
        public boolean LoadFullModelFromFile(Pointer calcer, String filename);
        public boolean CalcModelPrediction(Pointer calcer, size_t docCount,
                Pointer[] floatFeatures, size_t floatFeaturesSize,
                Pointer[] catFeatures, size_t catFeaturesSize,
                Pointer result, size_t resultSize);
    }
```

After that, I populate the `floatFeatures` and `catFeatures` parameters like this (some dummy data here). Note that for strings I'm using JNA's `StringArray`.

```
float[] floatFeatures = {0.4f, 0.8f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.1f, 0.5f, 0.4f, 0.8f, 0.3f, 0.3f} ;
String[] catFeatures = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};

final Pointer pFloatFeatures = new Memory(floatFeatures.length * Native.getNativeSize(Float.TYPE));
final Pointer[] ppFloatFeatures = new Pointer[2];
for (int dloop=0; dloop<10; dloop++) {
    pFloatFeatures.setFloat(dloop * Native.getNativeSize(Float.TYPE), floatFeatures[dloop]);
}
ppFloatFeatures[0] = pFloatFeatures;
ppFloatFeatures[1] = pFloatFeatures;

final Pointer[] ppCatFeatures = new Pointer[catFeatures.length];
final Pointer pCatFeatures = new StringArray(catFeatures);
ppCatFeatures[0] = pCatFeatures;
ppCatFeatures[1] = pCatFeatures;
```

Finally, I pass these parameters to Catboost:

```
if (!catboost.CalcModelPrediction(
                modelHandle,
                new size_t(2L),
                ppFloatFeatures, new size_t((long)floatFeatures.length),
                ppCatFeatures, new size_t((long)catFeatures.length),
                pResult, new size_t(2L)
                ))
{
    throw new RuntimeException("No prediction made: " + catboost.GetErrorString());
}
```

To get predictions we can do:

```
double[] result = pResult.getDoubleArray(0, 2);
```